# Change button text in code for Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is an extremely basic question and I'm embarrassed I haven't been able to find the solution online.

I would like to be able to update the text of my button in code. I am using the new Android Studio IDE. I created a blank activity when starting the project and placed a `Button` in activity_main.xml. How do I access this button in code to change its properties? I am trying in the mainactivity.java file but the intellisense isn't giving me anything that looks promising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

// Clean the code then

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

Answer (score 16):

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setText("Click Me !");
```

I hope this helps you.